# Duplicate of a closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

[This recent story-ID question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272436/futuristic-novel-where-war-is-unconstitutional-and-people-have-limbs-amputated-b) is a duplicate of [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144951/looking-for-sci-fi-book-name) with the same answer accepted in a comment by the OP. Unfortunately, that old question was closed by the site police for allegedly needing "more focus".

Can I close the new question as a duplicate of a closed question? Or do we just let the two questions and answers remain as they are, without being marked as duplicates?

Comment: I like to think of us as volunteer firefighters rather than site police

Comment: I thought changing "crazed lynch mob" to "site police" was euphemistic enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've reopened the closed older question and subsequently closed it as a duplicate of the newer one. The newer question and answer pair are better quality so it makes sense to have that as the duplicate "hub".

In general it's best not to close questions as duplicates to closed questions (if the system lets you). As this was a [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) question the best bet is to reopen and duplicate close to the better question and answer pair. In non-Id cases I would probably recommend treating the question as if the closed duplicate doesn't exist in most cases.